# Turkey Visa Upon Arrival for Syrian Citizen

Tags: visas, turkey, syrian-citizens

I am a Syrian national and I have a Schengen visa valid for two years. I want to go for a visit to Turkey.

My question: can I get my visa upon arrival for 30 days in the airport authority in Istanbul ?

Answer (score 3):

**No You cannot get a visa upon arrival**,You will have to apply to the nearest Turkish Embassy/consulate for a visa as a Syrian citizen.

> Syrian Citizens need a Visa upon entry in Turkey. From official
>   wikipedia visa policy of Turkey:
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Turkey

[image]

> There is no e visa facility for Syrian citizens. From official
>   Republic Of turkey Electronic Visa Application System :

https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/noevisa/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Unfortunately not.**

Syrian citizens are [required to obtain a visa](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa) before travelling to Turkey and aren't even [eligible for an eVisa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/who-is-eligible-for-e-visa/), according to the Turkish Ministry of Foreign Affairs.

> Syria: Ordinary and official passport holders are required to have
>   visa to enter Turkey.

[Timatic says the same.](http://www.emirates.com/ca/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=SY&NV=Syria&DC=TR&DV=Turkey&h=c955c917141bddcc89726331ac2a188cb4a6b87)

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: who downvoted you, +1

Comment: @AliAwan haha thanks man. I see you've edited my other question too :)